# add icon-class on nav based on URL

Tags: javascript, url, prepend

I am not really a web programmer and neither a english speaker, so excuse myself if I said something illogical.

I am trying to add an icon-class on every 'li' item of the navigation based on the URL that is active, I don´t know if it is important but I am using twitter bootstrap. The HMTL:

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Inici</a></li>
   <li><a href="servi.html">Serveis</a></li>
   <li><a href="acti.html">Activitats</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contacte</a></li>
   <li id="date"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></li>
</ul>
```

The Javascript:

```
function activeLinkNav(){

  var href = location.href.toLowerCase();
  var separa = href.split('/'); // cut the string on '/'
  var lastUri = separa[separa.length-1]; // accessing last item [separa]


$('.nav li a').each(function(){
    if (href.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase())> -1){

        switch (true){

            case lastUri == 'index.html':
                $(this).prepend('<span><i class="icon-home"></i></span>');
                break;

            case lastUri == 'servi.html':
                $(this).prepend('<span><i class="icon-user-md"></i></span>');
                break;

            case lastUri.indexOf('acti.html')!== -1:
                $(this).prepend('<span><i class="icon-group"></i></span>');
                break;

            case lastUri == 'contact.html':
                $(this).prepend('<span><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>');
                break;
        }

    } else $(this).prepend('<i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i>');
});
}
```

Everything is working fine except when I am accessing to the root domain, debugging my code I see that lastUri = ""; so why if I put this:

```
            case lastUri == "":
                $(this).prepend('<span><i class="icon-home"></i></span>');
                break;
```

the code is not working?

I´ve tried a lot of things but this is all my knowledge, any idea?

The web in question:

http://residencia-geriatrica-ergos.com/

Thanks!!

Comment: You might want to look at PHP. Depending on the URL the Server will prepare different HTML documents. Java Script modifies the document at the client level. It is much slower and somewhat unnecessary. If you are willing to use PHP, let me know and I will write an PHP-based answer for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Raffael, but PHP is too much for me and I prefer a javascript option, although if you don´t mind to write it for a further projects it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `if (href.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase())> -1)`
will not be true.
`href` will be equal to "http://residencia-geriatrica-ergos.com/"
and `this.href` will be equal to "index.html", thus it will not be found in href.

My suggestion:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var href = location.href.toLowerCase();
  switch(href):
     case 'http://residencia-geriatrica-ergos.com/':
       $('a[href="index.html"]').prepend('<span><i class="icon-home"></i></span>'); //append active icon
       $('li:not(.active) a').prepend('<i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i>'); //append standard icons
     break;
     case 'http://residencia-geriatrica-ergos.com/index.html':
       $('a[href="index.html"]').prepend('<span><i class="icon-home"></i></span>');
       $('li:not(.active) a').prepend('<i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i>'); //append standard icons
     break;
     case 'http://residencia-geriatrica-ergos.com/servi.html':
       $('a[href="servi.html"]').prepend('<span><i class="icon-home"></i></span>');
       $('li:not(.active) a').prepend('<i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i>'); //append standard icons
     break;
   //add other
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks a lot, was easier than I thought